# How to show NULL value using GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using gridview to fetch the data from sqlserver. there are few values which are NULL.
How to show these values using Gridview?

Comment: in sql server you can do something like `SELECT ISNULL(ColumnName, 'no value')`

Comment: how do you want to display them? as the word "NULL", a blank, etc?

Comment: Yes! but how to do it using asp.net to show on a webpage?

Comment: As a NULL...... @psoshmo

Comment: Do you want handle nulls on sql server side or in c#? if either one is fine, Ali's comment is answer.

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(ColumnName, 'NULL')

Comment: using C#....@DarkKnight

Comment: If it is in c#, you need to consider different factors like how you are retrieving data from database, type of datasource etc. Easiest way is to handle it in sql as i said in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your feedback in comments, use this..

```
SELECT ISNULL(ColumnName, 'NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you,

```
 <asp:GridView ID="id" runat="server" CellPadding="4">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>                          
                            <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("columnName")) == null ? 'any text you want to write' : Eval("columnName") %>                         
                    </ItemTemplate>                     
                </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you are converting it to string and comparing with keyword Null. dont you see an issue?